# simple jquery tabs integration into a gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I implement in my gallery a tabbing system, I have two tabs "gallery1" and "gallery2", first tab it's ok but 2nd tab loads only 1 image,

I've found this

`<div class="container" style="margin-left: 10px; width: 0px; left: 0px;">`

and I removed the width but the horizontal scrolling of the thumbnails doesn't work.

I think something is positioned incorrect in css or in the html markup(the integration of tabs in actual gallery) because the javascript code is fine ( if I remove the tabs the gallery is showing properly).

Check out this [link](http://outboxvision.com/BubblerifficImageGallery/) to see what I'm talking about.

Or give me another solution for not displaying both thumbnail containers simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Scripts can't work without the actual container visible.

Try setting up the Tabs script after initializing the gallery, and make sure both tabs are visible on gallery init.

Comment: the Tabs script begins with   "$(document).ready(function() { "   and the gallery script begins with " $(window).load(function() {" is this a problem ?

Comment: Initialization is not in the same place? Change this!

Comment: so, you are saying to put both scripts in one? I've tried to put the tabs script in the gallery script but the gallery didn't work

Comment: I mean: you can keep both scripts separate, but the initialization of your application should be in one place and completely under your control.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the width tag of div:

this time is : `<div class="container" style="margin-left: 10px; left: 0px; width: 0pt;">`

now changed:`<div class="container" style="margin-left: 10px; left: 0px;">`

I have work in inspect Element of browser and and show all images in both tabs.

Please remove "width" tag .

Comment: I've said that I removed the width and the horizontal scrolling effect doesn't work if I do that, basically you're answering my question with my question

Comment: yes i read you said width is remove but width tag is confilt to horizontal effect.

Comment: yes I know is in conflict but if I remove the width, as I said, the horizontal scrolling effect doesn't work